# Java drawOval after random time when user pressed Jbutton

Tags: java, timer, jbutton

So when the user presses my JButton, it picks a random time, and after that time, it will draw a oval to the screen. However, with what I have now, it draws the oval right after the button is pressed. I want it to appear after a random time.

```
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
  {
  if (e.getSource() == startButton)
  {
      popUpTime = random.nextInt(5000);
      timer = new Timer(popUpTime, this);

      x = random.nextInt(400) + 70;
          y = random.nextInt(400) + 100;

          points[current++] = new Point(x, y);

      timer.start();
      start();

      repaint();
  }


   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the sleep function from the Thread class to make the program wait for a random time. Something like this:

```
try{
Thread.sleep(PopUpTime);
}
catch(Exception e)
{}
// and then compute new points and repaint
```

Comment: that is not a good idea, you are blocking the Event Dispatch Thread.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your logic:

```
if event is start button, then setup oval and timer and call repaint();
```

assumedly repaint is drawing your oval at the set coordinates.

You probably should do something like this:

```
if (e.getSource() == startButton)  {
  drawOval = false;  // flag to repaint method to NOT display oval
  // setup timer 
  repaint();  // oval will not be drawn
else {
  // assuming timer has fired (which is a bit weak)
  x = ....;
  y = ...;
  drawOval = true;
  repaint();  // oval will be drawn.
}
```

Your repaint() method will need to check the drawOval setting:

```
public void repaint() {
  if (drawOval) {
    // draw it
  } else {
    // may need to clear oval
  }

  // draw other stuff.
}
```

Comment: The comment `// setup timer` is where I meant you to put it.